# Math operation datagridview

Tags: c#, visual-studio

I'm trying to do some operation in a datagridview,like this

```
object value1 = matematicaDataGridView[1, 0].Value;
object value2 = matematicaDataGridView[2, 0].Value;

int val1, val2;
if (int.TryParse(value1.ToString(), out val1) && int.TryParse(value2.ToString(), out val2))
{
    matematicaDataGridView[3,0].Value = val1 - val2;
}
else
{
    MessageBox.Show(" invalid inputs.");
}
```

i get the result from a single row,how can i get result from all the row in the datagridview ?

Comment: What math operation you are doing? Can you explain what exactly what your code is doing?

Comment: Use variable in loops instead of literals, e,g `matematicaDataGridView[i,j]`.

Comment: do you know how to use a for-loop ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to use a loop with a counter variable (`r`) to iterate through the rows and execute your code on each row:

```
for(int r=0; r<matematicaDataGridView.Rows.Count; r++)
{
    object value1 = matematicaDataGridView[1, r].Value;
    object value2 = matematicaDataGridView[2, r].Value;

    int val1, val2;
    if (int.TryParse((string)value1, out val1) && int.TryParse((string)value2, out val2))
    {
        matematicaDataGridView[3, r].Value = val1 - val2;
    }
    else
    {
        //MessageBox.Show(" invalid inputs.");
    }
}
```

Since `value1` can be null, `value1.ToString()` may raise an exception. to avoid it, you could use `(string)value1` instead.